# grab remote shell script then run it with parameter in localhost

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

i have uploaded a test script `remote.sh` to a remote webserver like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo "input var is : $1"
```

and i have a local script `local.sh` like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

curl -sS https://remote_host/remote.sh | bash
```

then i run the local script with some inline parameter :

```
./local.sh "some input here."
```

but the remote script i grabbed doesn't seem to see the local inline parameter.  how can this be done ?

Comment: Tag bash **or** zsh, not both at the same time; the two shells are deeply and mutually incompatible. In this case, since your code explicitly uses bash, it should _just_ be bash.

Comment: (indeed, zsh looking as much like bash as it does, while having gratuitous compatibilities everywhere zsh's authors consider POSIX-mandated behavior unwise, is exactly why some folks from the POSIX world -- myself included -- consider using zsh unwise: it gets one accompanied to muscle memory that leads to serious bugs when applied to POSIX-y shells; compare to non-POSIX shells like fish, [nushell](https://www.nushell.sh/), [elvish](https://elv.sh/), etc. which don't _smell_ POSIX-y, so they don't run as much risk as teaching people habits that result in bugs when targeting standard shells).

Comment: ("gratuitous" might have been a bit strong; honestly, zsh's design decisions are generally better than the ones inherited via POSIX from 1970s and 1980s shells; the problem is that they're making these better decisions at the expense of using syntax that _looks_ like it works but is subtly buggy when used on said backwards-compatible shells).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is starting a second copy of bash, and not passing the arguments retrieved to it.

I would generally suggest *not* starting a second copy of bash at all:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
eval "$(curl -sS https://remote_host/remote.sh)"
```

...but you could proceed to do so and pass them through. The following passes that code on the command line, leaving stdin free (so the new copy of bash being started can use it to prompt the user):

```
#!/bin/sh
code=$(curl -sS https://remote_host/remote.sh) || exit
exec bash -c "$code" bash "$@"
```

...or, to continue using stdin to pass code, `bash -s` can be used:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -sS https://remote_host/remote.sh | bash -s -- "$@"
```

By the way -- everywhere I use `/bin/sh` above you could substitute `/bin/bash` or any other POSIX-compliant shell; the point being made is that the code given above does not depend on behaviors that are unspecified in the POSIX.2 standard.